# Gatsby encountered with error "ERROR UNKNOWN - Store not found"

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I pumped into this issue while running Gatsby. Not sure what store is doing here but seems that it has something to do with the `gatsby-source-wordpress]`

```
store.ts:56 getStore
    [-website]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/src/store.ts:56:11
  
  - get-gatsby-api.ts:10 getGatsbyApi
    [-website]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/src/utils/get-gatsby-api.ts:10:11
  
  - content-update-interval.js:80 refetcher
    [-website]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/content-updat
    e-interval.js:80:43
  
  - content-update-interval.js:159 Timeout._onTimeout
    [-website]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/src/steps/source-nodes/update-nodes/content-updat
    e-interval.js:159:9
```

here is the Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^5.12.3",
    "gatsby-cli": "^5.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links": "^1.2.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps": "^3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.12.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.12.0",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^7.12.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.12.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  },
```

And here's the `gatsby-source-wordpress` in gatsby-config.js

```
 {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        url: process.env.GATSBY_WPGRAPHQL_URL,
        auth: {
          htaccess: {
            username: process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_PASSWORD,
          },
        },
```

I tried to google it around but found nothing. Hope someone has encountered this could provide some helps or insights.

Comment: I have the same issue, no luck so far